# Expanding a message template

Tags: c#, regex

I have a set of templates for emails that my app sends out. The templates have codes embedded in them that correspond to properties of my business object.

Is there a more elegant way than calling

```
string.Replace("{!MyProperty!}", item.MyProperty.ToString())
```

a zillion times? Maybe XMLTransform, regular expressions, or some other magic? I'm using C# 3.5 .

Answer (score 3):

First of all, when I do this I use StringBuilder.Replace() as I have found that its performance is much better suited when working with 3 or more replacements.

Of course there are other ways of doing it, but I've found that it is not usually worth the extra effort to try other items.

You might be able to use Reflection I guess to automate the replacement, that might be the only "better" way.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string Translate(string pattern, object context)
{
    return Regex.Replace(pattern, @"\{!(\w+)!}", match => {
        string tag = match.Groups[1].Value;
        if (context != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = context.GetType().GetProperty(tag);
            if (prop != null)
            {
                object value = prop.GetValue(context);
                if (value != null)
                {
                    return value.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    });
}
```

```
Translate("Hello {!User!}. Welcome to {!GroupName!}!", new {
    User = "John",
    GroupName = "The Community"
}); // -> "Hello John. Welcome to The Community!"
```

https://ideone.com/D9J31c

Comment: I added this, along with the other solutions.  It removed the fields that didn't have matches, while using the other solutions to efficiently fill in the available fields.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using a regex, but your regex replace differs also for each property. I would stick with the `string.Replace`.

Use reflection to retrieve the properties and replace it in a loop:

```
foreach (string property in properties)
{
  string.Replace("{!"+property+"!}",ReflectionHelper.GetStringValue(item,property));
}
```

Just implement your `ReflectionHelper.GetStringValue` method and use reflection to retrieve all the properties on your item object type.

Answer (score 1):

There's a built in WebControl, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.MailDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.maildefinition.aspx) that does [string replacements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156159.aspx) (among other things). Pity they tightly coupled it to the Smtp settings in app.config and a web control, and then made it sealed to foil inheritors.

But, it does handle a few things you'd most likely want in a mail template engine - body text from a file, html email, embedded objects, etc. Reflector shows the actual replacement is handled with a foreach loop and Regex.Replace - which seems a reasonable choice to me as well.

A quick glance through shows that if you can live with the from address being in the app.config (you can change it on the returned MailMessage afterwards), you only need the owner control for embedded resources or the BodyFileName.

If you're using ASP.NET or can live with the limitations - I'd choose MailDefinition. Otherwise, just do a foreach over a dictionary and a Regex.Replace. It's a little memory hungry, because of the repeated allocations of body - but they're short lived and shouldn't pose much of a problem.

```
var replacements = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
    { "Property1", obj.Property1 },
    { "Property2", obj.Property2 },
    { "Property3", obj.Property3 },
    { "Property4", obj.Property4 },
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in replacement) {
    body = Regex.Replace(body, kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString());
}
```

If you really have *a lot* of properties, then read your body first with Regex.Match and reflect to the properties instead.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the examples previously included, I thought I'd look at the real code.
@mark-brackett You were closer than you knew.

```
//The guts of MailDefinition.CreateMailMessage
//from https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/UI/WebControls/MailDefinition.cs

if (replacements != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(body)) {
                    foreach (object key in replacements.Keys) {
                        string fromString = key as string;
string toString = replacements[key] as string;

                        if ((fromString == null) || (toString == null)) {
                            throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.MailDefinition_InvalidReplacements));
                        }
                        // DevDiv 151177
                        // According to http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx, some special 
                        // constructs (starting with "$") are recognized in the replacement patterns. References of
                        // these constructs will be replaced with predefined strings in the final output. To use the 
                        // character "$" as is in the replacement patterns, we need to replace all references of single "$"
                        // with "$$", because "$$" in replacement patterns are replaced with a single "$" in the 
                        // final output. 
                        toString = toString.Replace("$", "$$");
                        body = Regex.Replace(body, fromString, toString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    }
                }
```